# External interrupts in STM32CubeMx on both Rising/Falling?

Tags: stm32cubemx, gpio-external-interrupt

I'm using STM32Cube to generate the configuration. It creates the following code by default for MX_GPIO_Init in main.c:

```
...
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
...
```

However, I also want it to be triggered on falling, so I have to manually change it to:

```
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING_FALLING;
```

Since I need regularly to change the setup (because I am both a starter, and want to gradually add pins), is there a way in STM32CubeMX to set this, so it is generated?

Comment: You need to disable interrupts before changing the trigger edge. maybe run it as an ISR?

Comment: @Sparky256 it's not about the code execution/order, it's about the generation of code from STM32CubeMX. I would expect a field/widget somewhere inside STM32CubeMX to set the trigger edge type (falling/rising/falling+rising).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In STM32CubeMX under:
Configuration -> GPIO -> GPIO -> GPIO Mode

[image]